# Access 2002/VBA - IIf

Tags: ms-access, syntax, vba

Consider:

```
sqlAddress = "SELECT " _
& "address_line_1, address_line_2, city, postcode, state " _
& "FROM contacts " _
& "WHERE (contact_id =" & contact_id & ")"

Set rsAddress = dbs.OpenRecordset(sqlAddress)

If Not rsAddress.EOF Then
    addressStr = IIf(rsAddress("address_line_2")='', rsAddress("address_line_1") & Chr(13) + Chr(10) & rsAddress("city") & Chr(13) + Chr(10) & rsAddress("postcode") & Chr(13) + Chr(10) & rsAddress("state"), rsAddress("address_line_1") & Chr(13) + Chr(10) & rsAddress("address_line_2") & Chr(13) + Chr(10) & rsAddress("city") & Chr(13) + Chr(10) & rsAddress("postcode") & Chr(13) + Chr(10) & rsAddress("state"))
    Me.vcTBAddress.SetFocus
    Me.vcTBAddress = addressStr
End If
```

What I want this to do is to ONLY display the address_line_2 in case it is not null and it is not an empty string.  The IIf is returning a syntax error.  I cannot see why - what am I missing please?

Comment: Replace `rsAddress("address_line_2")=''` with `rsAddress("address_line_2")=""`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, of course, that I have stuffed up the empty string test: 
`rsAddress("address_line_2")=''`.

The correct syntax is: `rsAddress("address_line_2")=""` with double quotes `"`, not single quotes `'`.

Comment: Mistakes happen. As long as you learn from them no harm done.